# I have a activity when user clicks a card in it it goes to an fragment.. and return to that activity how to destroy that fragment?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6G7Yh.png)
I want to stop fragment when user picks orderdate and deliveryDate.

I have an activity inside that a two cards oderDate and deliveryDate when the user clicks any one of them it goes to a fragment to pick a date and i want to stop that fragment when user pick dates.

orderActivity.xml

```
 orderDateCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                isOrder = 1; // setting orderCard is true
                isDel = 0;

                fragmentContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                calender_view_fragment calender_view_fragment = new calender_view_fragment();
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragmentContainer, calender_view_fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();


            }
        });
        delDateCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                isDel = 1; //setting deliveryCard is true
                isOrder = 0;

                fragmentContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                calender_view_fragment calender_view_fragment = new calender_view_fragment();
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragmentContainer, calender_view_fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });
```

calender_view_fragment.xml

```
calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView calendarView, int selectedYear, int selectedMonth, int selectedDate) {
            orderYear = selectedYear;
            orderMonth = selectedMonth + 1;
            orderDate = selectedDate;


            calenderViewText.setText("PICK DELIVERY DATE");
            calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView calendarView, int selectedYear, int selectedMonth, int selectedDate) {
                    delDate = selectedDate;
                    delMonth = selectedMonth + 1;
                    delYear = selectedYear;
                    startOrderActivity();
                    stopCurrentFragment();


                }
            });


        }
    });
}

public void stopCurrentFragment(){



       calender_view_fragment  calender_view_fragment=new calender_view_fragment();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(calender_view_fragment).commitAllowingStateLoss();


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

> getFragmentManager().popBackStack()

Comment: add this code where you want to remove fragment from stack.So you can this code after selection of date.Let me know if it works for you

Comment: its not working when back button pressing it goes to that fragment

Comment: yes , i want to remove calender_view_fragment when user clicks a date .

Comment: remove startOrderActivity I think you are adding activity again and add code getFragmentManager().popBackStack().if its not   working then share startOrderActivity  method.

Comment: not working, public void startOrderActivity(){
        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), OrderActivity.class));
    }